# Calling class method within WebSocket object

Tags: javascript, websocket, this

I have a class `Gadget` with one method `consider` defined as:

```
function Gadget() {

    this.consider = function (arg) {
        alert(arg);
    };

    if ("WebSocket" in window) {
        var ws = new WebSocket(...);
        // the rest truncated

        ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
            consider(evt.data);
        };
    }
}
```

I am, however, unable to get `consider` to work since it fails with a `TypeError`.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Gadget> has no method 'consider'
```

If I try using `this.consider` instead, the `TypeError` occurs with the *WebSocket* object. If I try `parent.consider`, then the *Object* object gives me the same error.

Right now my workaround is to use the method from a declared instance, as in:

```
var player = new Gadget();
```

and with `player.consider(evt.data)` instead. I don't like to do this, but it works. How can I rearrange the code so that it doesn't depend on a defined instance of the object?

Comment: `var self=this; ws.onmessage=function(evt){self.consider(evt.data);};`

Comment: This would make it accessible within the function, I guess? Hmm, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways you can overcome this.

1) Use private function

```
function Gadget() {

    function consider(arg){
        alert(arg);
    }

    this.consider = consider;

    if ("WebSocket" in window) {
        var ws = new WebSocket(...);
        // the rest truncated

        ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
            consider(evt.data);
        };
    }
}
```

This way you have a private `consider()` function inside your `Gadget` class, that even if the instance of it tempered its own `consider` method (e.g. `var x=new Gadget(); x.consider=...`), the web socket will still work as you intended;

2) "Cache" `this`

```
function Gadget() {
    this.consider = function(arg){
        alert(arg);
    };

    if ("WebSocket" in window) {
        var ws = new WebSocket(...);
        // the rest truncated

        var self=this;
        ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
            self.consider(evt.data);
        };
    }
}
```

This way your web socket event will always use whatever the *instance of Gadget* want `consider` to be.

[Here is a jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HGTE6/2/) that demonstrate these two ways. Notice that I intentionally tempered the `consider` method of the *instance of `Gadget2`* (the second button). Click those buttons to see the different.

Comment: I used a variation of your 2nd solution as in the comment before. I just declared `var self = this;` inside the `if` block. Thanks!

Comment: @icedwater Oops, my bad. I meant to put `var self=this` inside `if`, but since there's no `if` in my fiddle I just partly copied the code at your question without paying too much attention.